# Получение данных из таблицы по названиям столбца и строки

Tags: javascript

Есть таблица наподобие таблицы Пифагора.
Если известны цифра/буква из столбца (слева) и цифра из строки (сверху), то как узнать цифру/букву, стоящую на пересечении в таблице?

[image]

Comment: Матрица двумерная?

Comment: Не много не понял вопрос? но она же не трёх мерная...

Comment: Конечно не 3D, поэтому и сказал 2D.

Comment: Матрица типа `[..., ['O', 'P', 'Q', 'R'], ...]`. Выходит, при координатах `1:2` нужно обратиться как-то так: `matrix[1][2]; // Q`.

Comment: Думаю намного проще, здесь просматривается 16ричная система, если код разложить, но вот как привязаться на js не могу понять...

Comment: Я Вам сказал как. Массивы и координаты.

Comment: А другие варианты... ибо код будет гигантский...

Comment: Отнюдь, пропорционален таблице.

Comment: Мне кажется или это кто-то регистрирует каждый день новые аккаунты и делает нечто напоминающее шахматы?

Comment: Пример покажите?

Comment: OlmerDale от чего вы взяли? я сегодня зарегистрировался, так как знаю про ресурс, у меня ест вопрос, с которым я не смог справится, спросил совета, и кстати шахматы намного легче...

Comment: Неужели никто не видит закономерность?

Comment: Вы бы ещё спросили "неужели никто не умеет читать мысли?" Вы условия своей задачи не сказали. Может быть, таблица статическая и никаких данных в неё никогда не будет вноситься. Это характерно для олимпиадных, искусственных задач. А если бы вы были бы профессиональным программистом, который получает деньги за свою работу, да каждый день сталкивались с "кровавым" энтырпрайзом, из вас бы быстро эту дурь выбило -- верить бизнесу, что в этом справочнике никаких новых значений не предвидится. А на ru-so телепаты всегда в отпуске, ваши мысли не видят. Так что фигачить матрицу пока самый лучший совет

Comment: >>таблица статическая и никаких данных в неё никогда не будет вноситься.<< Да так и есть, изменения вносится не будут.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Без использования матрицы из-за закономерности в расположении букв в таблице:

```js
function getLetter(left, up)
{
    var number = fromHex(up) * 16 + fromHex(left);
    var letterCode = 32;
    if (number >= 2 && number <= 27)
    {
        letterCode = number + 63;
    }
    else if (number >= 28 && number <= 37)
    {
        letterCode = number + 20;
    }
    else if (number >= 38 && number <= 63)
    {
        letterCode = number + 59;
    }
    return String.fromCharCode(letterCode);
}

function fromHex(char)
{
    return parseInt(char + "", 16);
}

var letter = getLetter('C', '2');
console.log(letter);
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло...

Comment: Извините за назойливость, как с инпутов получить координаты... https://jsfiddle.net/1a8xjaue/1/ где то ошибка

Comment: @octopus по-хорошему, это стоило задавать отдельным вопросом. Вы бы тогда и ответ быстрее получили. А вообще - [как-то так](https://jsfiddle.net/1a8xjaue/2/).

Comment: Всё понял, спасибо.... дурной вопрос - почему айди инпутов а не класс? никогда не думал что есть связь приоритетов...

Answer (score 2):

```
// Первое значение — ось Y, второе — X, 
var out = getItem('b', '0')
console.log(out) // "J"

function getItem(y, x) {
    // Тут переводим шестнадцатиричное число 
    // в десятиричное, если требуется
    var args = arguments
    for(var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        if(typeof args[i] === 'string') {
            args[i] = parseInt(args[i], 16) 
        }
    }

    // Возвращаем ячейку по координатам
    return [
        //0,   1,   2,   3 
        [   , 'O', '4', 'k'], // 0
        [   , 'P', '5', 'l'], // 1
        ['A', 'Q', '6', 'm'], // 2
        ['B', 'R', '7', 'n'], // 3
        ['C', 'S', '8', 'o'], // 4
        ['D', 'T', '9', 'p'], // 5
        ['E', 'U', 'a', 'q'], // 6
        ['F', 'V', 'b', 'r'], // 7
        ['G', 'W', 'c', 's'], // 8
        ['H', 'X', 'd', 't'], // 9
        ['I', 'Y', 'e', 'u'], // a
        ['J', 'Z', 'f', 'v'], // b
        ['K', '0', 'g', 'w'], // c
        ['L', '1', 'h', 'x'], // d
        ['M', '2', 'i', 'y'], // e
        ['N', '3', 'j', 'z'], // f
    ][y][x]
}
```

Comment: Близко, но первое сравнивание должно быть по Y

Comment: Можно поменять  в аттрибутах x и y местами

Answer (score 0):

Можете это подогнать под свое решение, где будут цифры и заглавные, маленкие буквы. надеюсь что помог

```
var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split("");
_.each(alphabet, function(letter) {
  console.log(letter);
});
```